# How can you display Typing Speed using Javascript or the jQuery library?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a typing speed indicator just below the textarea we use on our contact form. It is just for fun and to give the user some interactivity with the page while they are completing the form.

It should display the average speed while typing and keep the last average when the keystrokes are idle. When they leave the textarea the last average should stick.

Ideally I would like to have a jQuery plugin if it is available.

[Edit] this was originally for just a few of my websites. But after I posted the question it struck me how this would be a neat feature for SO. If you agree [vote here](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/32755)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a tested implementation,which seems ok, but I don't guarantee the math.

A Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/pLpx5oLf/

And the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Type Speed</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            form {
                margin: 20px auto;
                width: 500px;
            }

            #textariffic {
                width: 400px;
                height: 400px;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-family: monospace;
                line-height: 15px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('textarea')
                    .keyup(checkSpeed);
            });

            var iLastTime = 0;
            var iTime = 0;
            var iTotal = 0;
            var iKeys = 0;

            function checkSpeed() {
                iTime = new Date().getTime();

                if (iLastTime != 0) {
                    iKeys++;
                    iTotal += iTime - iLastTime;
                    iWords = $('textarea').val().split(/\s/).length;
                    $('#CPM').html(Math.round(iKeys / iTotal * 6000, 2));
                    $('#WPM').html(Math.round(iWords / iTotal * 6000, 2));
                }

                iLastTime = iTime;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="tipper">
            <textarea id="textariffic"></textarea>
            <p>
                <span class="label">CPM</span>
                <span id="CPM">0</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span class="label">WPM</span>
                <span id="WPM">0</span>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you mean to make this a wiki answer? You surely deserve some rep points for this detailed answer.

Comment: Wasn't sure what the wiki answer thing was.

Comment: I think you mean * 60000 (1 minute) not 6000 (6 seconds)

Comment: That's what I'd originally set it to, but the results were coming in pretty high, hence the math disclaimer.

Comment: @enobrev - whenever you set a Question or Answer to "wiki" you no longer earn reputation points.

Comment: Ah well, quite alright.  Only took a couple minutes to throw together, and I figure it would be good if people could correct any mistakes.  Glad it helped!!

Comment: A fiddle for the code since the original link doesn't work anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/pLpx5oLf/

Comment: @3zzy, I'd meant to do that after my server went down, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's my own ego involvement:

```
<textarea id="b" onblur="clc();"></textarea>
<script>
t=0;
document.getElementById('b').onkeypress=function()
{
t==0 ? s=new Date() : e=new Date();
t=1;
}
function clc()
{
d = e.getTime() - s.getTime();
c = b.value.length;
b.value += "\n"+c+"s in "+d+"ms: "+c/d+" cpms";
}
</script>
```

I spent over a week on this learning JavaScript from zero (cutting and cutting). This will be a good starting point. It's now so simple that needs bare explanation. You could add anything to it. Its the best known minimalist and purest form.

It just gives you all into a textarea:
[image]

Comment: This is great! Especially considering you learnt JS for this :) The only drawback is, if you click your mouse accidently outside the textarea then it screws up.

Answer (score 1):

Typing speed is generally computed in words per minute minus a penalty for typos. To do this it seems like you'd need an inline spell-checker at the very least, plus some  heavy lifting for languages and encoding schemes.  (And then it starts to get complicated; when does the clock start, for instance?  What do you do about people who are entering code?  How about copy-and-pasting?)

Comment: true. my original intent was to use it on a contact form so there will not be those issues of code or copy/paste like there is for SO.

Answer (score -1):

a horribly simple, **untested** implementation:

```
var lastrun = new Date();
textarea.onkeyup = function() {
    var words = textarea.value.split(' ');
    var minutes_since_last_check = somefunctiontogetminutesdifference(new Date(), lastrun);
    var wpm = (words.length-1)/minutes_since_last_check;
    //show the wpm in a div or something
};
```