# display current value of var to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable `speed`  controlled by the user from keyboard, and I want to display it current value all the time.
I tried:

```
var user_speed= 1; //init

<h3 style="float:left;" id="userspeed"></h3>

document.getElementById("userspeed").innerHTML = user_speed.toFixed(2);
```

but what I get is only `speed = 1` and it never changed.

Is there a way to keep changing the displayed value, without creating a function that fire each time the user change the speed and execute `document.getElementById()...` again?

Comment: You need **something** that executes and writes the variable to your `h3` after it's change, that's the only way.

Comment: You mean variable name `speed` or `user_speed`.. Check that the names are different

Comment: fixed. I meant user_speed of course, tnx @YosvelQuintero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `setInterval` to update the value like so:

```
var speed = 1; //init

setInterval(function(){
   document.getElementById("userspeed").innerHTML = user_speed.toFixed(2);
}, 1000);
```

This will update the value every 1 second (1000 ms).

Comment: Ok, this is also good idea.
Assuming I have 10 vars and the intervals you wrote - is that something that should bother the CPU?

Comment: If all variables are being updated within the same timer block of code, then it should not be a problem. But do not use different _setInterval_ calls for each variable as it would cause the individual threads to be triggered

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the initial value, because you are calling only once that code.

As you said, if you want to change the value you should need to create a call to that function in order to renew the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way around. You may have to use a function and an event. Because how would you know or trigger some calculation when you dont know on which point the user entered some keys?

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167752/how-can-you-display-typing-speed-using-javascript-or-the-jquery-library)

UPDATE: As you maybe know **setInterval**/**setTimeout** are evil!

If you take a look at this [link](http://idiallo.com/javascript/settimeout-and-setinterval-and-setevil), you will see that you should avoid those functions for not very good reasons. Simplified:

> ... The first argument is a string, you actually pass it some JavaScript that will be evaluated at a global namespace when the timer expires. Read the evils of evals again above and then come back. The good thing is that you are not required to pass in a string of JavaScript code. ...

Comment: I thought that maybe the inneHTML is kind of bind to the var and do it by itself